# Why the built-in type Partial of Typescript cannot use Interface

Tags: typescript

It is well known that TS integrates some complex types internally, such as `Partial`

```
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

But I got a lot of error when I used interface to define `Partial` like this

```
interface TPartial<T> {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG2RW.png)

Maybe my understanding of `interface` and `type` is not enough. I always thought they could be used to define `object`

Can anyone explain why it can't be used here

Answer (score 2):

The utility type [`Partial<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) that you've shown is an example of what is called a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), and mapped types are defined using [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases). It's not more complicated than that: it's just how mapped types work — you can't define them using interfaces.

To better understand the differences between aliases and interfaces, you can study the section of the TypeScript handbook called [Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces).